# Question Marks and Semi-colons appearing on my website

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website that is hosted by SiteGround. Suddenly there are numerous places on the website where apostrophes have being replaced by questions marks and commas replaced with semi-colons. It hasn't happened in all cases, but more than enough to be very noticeable. SG recently did a transfer of all websites to new servers.

Any idea what might have caused this?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Charset of your site.
Change your site charset="UTF-8" in the meta tags.